# C# -Pipeline Style event model

Tags: c#, design-patterns, pipeline, chain-of-responsibility

In ASP.NET Web Apps , events are fired in particluar order :

for simplicity   **Load => validation =>postback =>rendering**

Suppose I want to develop such pipeline -styled event

Example :

Event 1 [ "Audiance are gathering" ,Guys{ Event 2 and Event 3 Please wait until i signal }]

**after Event 1 finished it task**

Event 2 [ { Event 2, Event 3 "Audiance gathered! My task is over } ]

**Event 2 is taking over the control to perform its task**

Event 2 [ " Audiance are Logging in " Event 3 please wait until i signal ]

**after Event 2 finished it task**

.....

Event 3 [ "Presentation By Jon skeet is Over :) "]

With very basic example can anybody explain ,how can i design this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution, that is also close to what actually happens in ASP.NET:

```
class EventChain
{    
    public event EventHandler Phase1Completed;
    public event EventHandler Phase2Completed;
    public event EventHandler Phase3Completed;

    protected void OnPhase1Complete()
    {
        if (Phase1Completed != null)
        {
            Phase1Completed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        // Do Phase 1
        ...
        OnPhase1Complete();

        // Do Phase 2
        ...
        OnPhase2Complete();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how you can take a simple abstract class, and a simple extension method on a list of handlers, and implement the pipeline model you're talking about.  This is of course a trivialized example as I'm simply passing it a string as the event data.  but you can obviously customize to suit your situation.

the extension method `RaiseEvent` enumerates over the list of handlers and calls the `Handle` method on the handler to notify it of the event.

```
public abstract class Handler
{
  public abstract void Handle(string event);
}

public static class HandlerExtensions
{
  public static void RaiseEvent(this IEnumerable<Handler> handlers, string event)
  {
     foreach(var handler in handlers) { handler.Handle(event); }     
  }
}

...

List<Handler> handlers = new List<Handler>();
handlers.Add(new Handler1());
handlers.Add(new Handler2());

handlers.RaiseEvent("event 1");
handlers.RaiseEvent("event 2");
handlers.RaiseEvent("event 3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows Workflow Foundation is designed to do just this. There's 2 screencasts here you can take a look at on how to implement something like this.

http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvcstore-part-19a/

http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvcstore-part-21/